# Angular 8 docker container Cannot find module even though it is installed

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I am building an Angular 8 SPA. I have a Dockerfile that is built and run using a Docker Compose configuration.

The configuration has been working for several weeks, but today, it suddenly stopped working. I didn't make any changes to what was working previously.

The Angular app no longer compiles due to a module error and all development is now blocked due to this issue.

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-cookie-service'.
```

I tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing the ngx-cookie-service module
- Deleting and re-creating node_modules and package-lock.json
- Running npm cache clean
- Running docker system prune and re-building the image
- Manually changing the version of ngx-cookie-service
- Confirmed that the node_modules/ngx-cookie-service directory is present

**QUESTION:**

What other steps can I take to troubleshoot the issue?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "angular2-query-builder": "^0.4.2",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
### Local development only ###

FROM node:12.8-alpine

# Install bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Add `/home/node/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Copy code
COPY ./angular /home/node/app

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 4201:4201

RUN npm install

# Start Angular
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './client/angular/:/home/node/app'
      - '/home/node/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '4201:4201'
    depends_on:
      - server
```

Comment: updated you can check now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you copy the build in your Dockerfile during build then there is no need to mount the host directory in docker-compose.

```
# Copy code
COPY ./angular /home/node/app
```

This is enough to run the app so you can remove these from your Docker-compose.

```
      - './client/angular/:/home/node/app'
      - '/home/node/app/node_modules'
```

If you want to run form container mount the build directory with container.

```
      - './client/angular/:/home/node/app'
```

Also, you can debug the package. after installation list the package.

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm list
```

OR if the still issue persists then tries the package as a global package.

```
RUN npm i ngx-cookie-service -g
```

Sometimes the host bind modules not working as we expect due to different binaries so better to install at run time in docker-compose.

Add this in docker-compose file

```
command: sh -c "
  npm i &&
  ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: thanks! I first removed both volumes and it worked, however I need to mount the code in so that my local changes are mounted into the container. I tried removing the anonymous volume `/home/node/app/node_modules` but am getting the error message: `/bin/sh: ng: not found`

Comment: does the mount folder contain the `node modules`?

Comment: btw do you need this `NV PATH /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH`? and if yes then why?

Comment: the mount folder contains the node modules. I also tried installing the module globally and removing the ENV path command but the same issue persists. If I remove the module altogether the app compiles successfully.

Comment: BTw I have experienced such issue with node modules like binaries of node modules in the window was not working alpine. What is your Host OS?

Comment: I am using `node:12.8-alpine`. I also tried it with the `node:12` base image (debian) but was getting the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199652/discussion-between-adiii-and-pengz).

Answer (score 2):

After doing [@Alli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3288890/adiii)'s accepted answer I encountered an error `Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'` and I fixed it by telling my `Dockerfile` to install it like so:

```
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN npm install
```

For those Dockerizing Angular for development purposes, don't remove the volume definition so that any changes from your code will reflect in the container.

**Don't remove the volume definition for dev environment**

```
      - './client/angular/:/home/node/app'
      - '/home/node/app/node_modules'
```